# Prove divergence of a product of sequences using contradiction

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a sequence converges (not to zero) and another sequence diverges, prove by contradiction that the product of these sequences is divergent.

This is a past test paper question that I am looking at and I really have no idea how to write the proof. My own working doesn't make any sense (even to me...) Would really appreciate some help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n \to l$ and $b_n$ be divergent. If possible let $a_nb_n$ be convergent. Note that $|a_n|>\frac {|l|}  2>0$, so $a_n \neq 0$,  for $n$ sufficiently large. Now $b_n =\frac 1 {a_n} {(a_nb_n)}$ for $n$ sufficiently large which makes $(b_n)$ convergent. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to clarify a few questions, is there a reason why we must also state  ||>||2>0 instead of just stating an not equals to zero? Also, for your last line, is it because we have assumed anbn to be convergent and since 1/an is also convergent, hence bn is convergent? and hence the contradiction? Thank you!

Comment: No. it is enough to say that $a_n \neq 0$ for $n$ sufficiently large. @abc123

Answer (score 0):

If $(a_n)$ converges to $L\neq 0$, then you have $\vert a_n \vert \ge \vert L \vert /2 >0$ for $n$ large enough. Let say $n\ge N$.

Now if the sequence $(b_n)$ diverges, either it is not bounded and therefore $(a_n b_n)$ is not bounded either and therefore diverges. And if $(b_n)$ is bounded (and doesn’t converge), it has at least two limit points $B_1,B_2$. $B_1 L, B_2 L$ are then two limit points of $(a_n b_n)$ that can’t converge.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was also wondering how to prove it without using contradiction, and you have done so here. Thank you for your help!